# Is there a parallel flood fill implementation?

Tags: parallel-processing, flood-fill

I've got openMP and MPI at my disposal, and was wondering if anyone has come across a parallel version of any flood fill algorithm (preferably in c). If not, I'd be interested in sketches of how to do parallelise it - is it even possible given its based on recursion?

Wikipedia's got a pretty good [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) if you need to refresh your memory on flood fills.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing "inherently" recursive about flood-fill, just that to do some work, you need some information about previously-discovered "frontier" cells.  If you think of it that way, it's clear that parallelism is eminently possible: even with a single queue, you could use four threads (one for each direction), and only move the tail of the queue when the cell has been examined by each thread.  or equivalently, four queues.  thinking in this way, one might even imagine partitioning the space into multiple queues - bucketed by coordinate ranges, perhaps.

one basic problem is that the problem definition usually includes the proviso that no cell is ever revisited.  this implies that each worker needs an up-to-date map of which cells have been considered (globally).  mutable global information is problematic, performance-wise, though it's not hard to think of ways to limit the necessity for propagating updates globally...