# Finding separate chunks in an image

Tags: image-processing, graphics, parallel-processing, compute-shader

I have a somewhat unusual question for a project, which I have not found the answer to anywhere.

Im building a game heavily relying on image processing for things like per-pixel collision and calculations on a very frequent tickrate, and one of the things I need to do is check if an image (in this case, representing a ship) is broken and constitutes of more than one part.

Example:

[image]

As you can see this ship is split (say by some weapon impact) and the left wing is now broken off. I need to determine which pixels were separated (for example by marking their alpha channel with 0).

Until now my method for the image processing portions of the program involved DirectCompute. it is working efficiently as all of the currently implemented functions can be parallelized - say, calculating the center of mass of the image is as easy as averaging the positions of pixels whose alpha is not 0.

This problem is different. What i had in mind in the beginning is using the cockpit position (i.e. the core of the ship) and floodfilling (using alpha>0 as connectivity) at that position, followed by filtering the pixels which weren't changed in the operation. However, this operation is not parallelizable (floodfill is recursive by nature) and implementing it on the CPU side would incur either a massive performance penalty, or a visible lag (lowering the tickrate would make the splitting reaction very unresponsive).

Is this problem solveable on a parallel basis, or do i need to resort to some other technique? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I suggest heading over to [our sister site, DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

whether to detect that it is broken or detect the pieces - I think the latter as based on your description

flood fill is not inherently recursive as can be exemplified by running it on the queue; and starting from this answer [Is there a parallel flood fill implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056075/is-there-a-parallel-flood-fill-implementation) the basic rationale is given, although not on how to implement it; You have to think and figure out how to implement it (searching with "parallel flood fill" will give you many results).

As for other ideas this is connected component analysis and it is basically as you describe as flood-fill.